# UIColor not matching RGB

Tags: ios, rgb, uicolor

I have an image in Fireworks. I am using the picker to choose the color and then look at the RGB values. I am putting these values into `UIColor:colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha` but it is not giving me the same output. I am using values between 1.0 and 0.0.

I am trying to get a dark blue color, the `UIColor` is giving me a very light blue.

Ideas?

Comment: What values are you passing to the class method?

Comment: copy&paste the UIColor instanciating and (if needed) instanciating of the RGB-values used. Also copy&paste the line where you assign that UIColor to an element. My bet is that you have a type-conversion mixup in your code. Ow, and please copy&paste the exact values that fireworks is showing you for that color.

Answer (score 10):

Sounds to me like your calculations for converting the value from fireworks to the value necessary in UIColor is off.

example:

Fireworks RGB values red:64 green:87 blue:188

divide those three number each by 255

gives you 
`[UIColor colorWithRed:0.250980392156863 green:0.341176470588235 blue:0.462745098039216 alpha:1.0]`

Comment: That basically worked, I tweaked it a few times till it looked how I wanted, the shading makes it a bit different than what I wanted. I tried doing [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:20/255 blue:109/255 alpha:1] , but that gave me black. If I do the calculations on the fly like this, it always seems to give me black.

Comment: if you want to do the calculations on the fly then you need to make them with decimals so it calculates them as floats since the method requires CGFloat values to be passed in.   in the example you use, 20/255 or 109/255 results in a 0 being passed in since you are doing division of integers not floats.  so simply make if 20.0f/255.0f and 109.0f/255.0f and it will then give you the color instead of giving you black.

Answer (score 7):

Add this to a header file: (something like helpers.h)

```
#define RGBCOLOR(r,g,b) [UIColor colorWithRed:(r)/255.0 green:(g)/255.0 blue:(b)/255.0 alpha:1]
```

Then add this to the YourApp_Prefix.pch file

```
#import "helpers.h"
```

Finally whenever you need a color you would use this:

```
UIColor* myColor = RGBCOLOR(64,87,188);
```

Comment: I think you mean UIColor myColor = RGBCOLOR(64,87,188);

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are retrieving float values by including decimal points in your statement.

```
UIColor *myColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:16.0/255 green:176.0/255 blue:230.0/255 alpha:1];
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define UIColorFromRGBWithAlpha(rgbValue,a) [UIColor \
colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:a]
```

## define kbackGroundColor UIColorFromRGB(0x00A99D)

use this code with best of RGB on hex Coloring....Cheers